# Github error while trying to push code from local to remote

Tags: git, github

I get the below error while I try to push my code from local to remote:

```
"To https://github.com/rishabhsrana/webdev.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
 error: failed to push some refs to '     https://github.com/rishabhsrana/webdev.git'
 hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
 hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository     pushing
 hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
 hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
 hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details."
```

Can someone please help me out how to resolve this, since I have no clue of how to proceed.

FYI, I tried clearing my commit history few minutes back using the following commands (although it got implemented successfully on cmd prompt, but my history is still intact on my github page):

```
git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo
now commit your current version of code

git add *
git commit -am 'message'
and finally force the update to GitHub:

git push -f origin master
```

Comment: Did you pull?   That's what the error message is suggesting you do.

Comment: read the *** error: `You may want to first integrate the remote changes (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting, is because you are attempting to push local changes that are "behind" the existing changes on the remote.

The solution here is to commit your local work (Which you have done) then pull from the remote. This will cause a merge (And potentially a merge-conflict). Resolve the merge-conflict if required, commit these merge-changes. Now, everything should be ready for a new "push" :)

Comment: Hi, I already tried it, when I do so I get a reply --> "Already up-to date". Even than when I am again trying to push my code, I still get the error posted above in the main question

Comment: Are you using the master branch locally? What you wrote is to pull data from the master branch, which makes little sense if you are actually on another branch.

Try "git branch" and post result here, also git status might give us more info.

Comment: Hi Stian, I have only one branch and i.e. master. Although as you requested, below are the results:

C:\Users\risha_000\CS5610Code>git branch
* master

C:\Users\risha_000\CS5610Code>git branch
* master

Comment: That's weird. Was this "git status" results as well?

Comment: Yes, it is the "git status" result as well :|

Comment: If you take backup of your current work (first) then do the following:

`git checkout master`

This should discard any commits you have and send you to the newest remote version.

Then you can try to redo your changes, commit and push; See if that works :)

Comment: This might help as I told above in the question. Before pushing my code, I wanted to delete "All commit history", so I had tried the following:

git init
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo
now commit your current version of code

git add *
git commit -am 'message'
and finally force the update to GitHub:

git push -f origin master

This all problem seems to be happening cuz of this!!

Would this help you? to figure out this issue!! I know its wierd!!



SURE, LEMME DO AS YOU SAID FIRST.

Comment: I tried with git checkout master, but got the following:

"C:\Users\risha_000\CS5610Code>git checkout master
M       .idea/workspace.xml
Already on 'master'
"

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure about this, but I think maybe your remote branch (On github) thinks it has some state, then when you ran the "git init" command, you created some other state, which is not comforming to the github state, which is causing you all this trouble.

To get on the right side (of github) again, you should clone the repository, which will give you the same state.

`git clone <repository>`

Then you can do any changes you want to this new local repository and commit them :)

Comment: First of all, thanks for your time :)

Sadly, even after creating clone of my repository: https://github.com/rishabhsrana/webdev  TO https://github.com/rishabhsrana/webdev/webdev2016 AND trying to commit again it didn't work out.

Comment: This seems very strange.. Does the problem happen to new repositories as well? So if you create a brand new one on github?

Comment: It's been more than 12 hours since I've been trying to resolve this issue (...exhausted...)
I tried various things and was finding my way out until a new error popped in:

Whenever I try to do ===> "git clone" or "git push" I get the error : Failed to connect to  git.gitorious.org port 1080: Connection refused".

And this is limited to my PC(Windows only), if I try to clone or push on my repo by some other laptop, it works absolutely fine....(sic)

Comment: Could there be a firewall on your windows PC? Could also be a problem in your git setup (in terms of user account/SSH keys/ etc). This error usually means that you hit a blocked port, or used the wrong information for authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

Try starting with `git pull origin master`

The error message says there are changes on the remote master which you don't have locally. In order to not wipe out those changes, you must pull before you push.

Answer (score 0):

You should pull from origin to get the latest code before pushing your changes.

```
git pull origin master
```

Comment: Hi, I already tried it, when I do so I get a reply --> "Already up-to date".
Even than when I am again trying to push my code, I still get the error posted above in the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for responding so quickly.

I had already tried ===> "git pull origin master" and got the below response:

```
"C:\Users\risha_000\CS5610Code>git pull origin master
 From ssh://webdevelopment-ranarishabhsingh.rhcloud.com/~/git/webdevelopment
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
 Already up-to-date."
```

I read the "git-push manual page" as well but frankly speaking I couldn't understand most of it.

Kindly suggest what to do, thanks for being patient, and please bear me with as I relatively inexperienced with this stuff, although I am trying to get familiar with it.